# SELECT distinct gives wrong count

Tags: sql, select, postgresql-9.2

I've got a problem where my `count(*)` will return the number of rows before distinct rows are filtered.

This is a simplified version of my query. Note that I'll extract a lot of other data from the tables, so `group by` won't return the same result, as I'd have to group by maybe 10 columns. The way it works is that `m` is a map mapping `q`, `c` and `kl`, so there can be several references to `q.id`. I only want one.

```
SELECT distinct on (q.id) count(*) over() as full_count
from q, c, kl, m 
where c.id = m.chapter_id
    and q.id = m.question_id
    and q.active = 1
    and c.class_id = m.class_id
    and kl.id = m.class_id
order by q.id asc
```

If I run this i get `full_count = 11210` while it only returns 9137 rows. If I run it without the `distinct on (q.id)`, distinct on (q.id) is indeed the number of rows.

So it seems that the count function doesn't have access to the filtered rows. How can I solve this? Do I need to rethink my approach?

Comment: you can use `COUNT(DISTINCT columnName)`

Comment: @dognose then I have to add it to `GROUP BY`. I might just have to drop the whole distinct and just use group by. Time for rewriting this monsterSQL I'm afraid.

Comment: Do you want the count *per* q.id?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just want the count() to represent the actual number of rows returned. See my comment on Gordons answer.

Comment: Btw: you should rewrite your join conditions using explicit JOINs.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think this query will be getting some rewriting. It's old code I "inherited" from someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a subquery:

```
select qid, count(*) over () as full_count
from (SELECT distinct q.id
      from q, c, kl, m 
      where c.id = m.chapter_id
            and q.id = m.question_id
            and q.active = 1
            and c.class_id = m.class_id
            and kl.id = m.class_id
     ) t
order by q.id asc
```

But the `group by` *is* the right approach.  The key word `distinct` in `select`is really just syntactic sugar for doing a group by on all non-aggregate-functioned columns.

Comment: You won my green checkmark by the last comment. I realised it isn't possible to do what I wanted to do without rewriting it so that the right fields were mentioned in `group by`. I deleted a lot of the data that I got from the tables that after looking into it was completely useless to me.

Comment: @jurgemaister . . . I see a lot of confusion about `distinct`.  I'm getting the idea that people learn `select distinct` before `group by`, and tend to prefer that keyword -- possibly causing confusion in the long term.  By the way, your original query is pretty clever, combining distinct *and* window functions.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the query is built with code, adding tables and search conditions dynamically. It can end up being quite huge, so I didn't want to mess too much with it. It all worked well until the map started to have several instances of question_id (the original version did not).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what exactly you are trying to count, but this might get you started:

```
select id, 
       full_count,
       id_count
from (
    SELECT q.id, 
           count(*) over() as full_count,
           count(*) over (partition by q.id) as id_count,
           row_number() over (partition by q.id order by q.id) as rn
    from q
      join m on q.id = m.question_id
      join c on c.id = m.chapter_id and c.class_id = m.class_id
      join kl on kl.id = m.class_id
    where q.active = 1
) t
where rn = 1
order by q.id asc
```

If you need the count *per id*, then the column `id_count` would be what you need. If you need the overall count, but just on row per id, then the `full_count` is probably what you want.

(note that I re-wrote your implicit join syntax to use explicit JOINs)

Comment: The joins are a nice touch. I'll use group by, but I'll implement the joins as well. Thanks.